# What's the relationship between subspaces U and W in $U+W, U\cup W$, and $U \bigoplus W$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given two subspaces, $U$ and $W$ of $V$, I know that $U+W$ and $U\cup W$ are related in that $U+W$ is the smallest subspace containing $U\cup W$, but what's their relationship in $U+W, U\cup W$, and $U \bigoplus W$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $U \cup V \subseteq U+V$ and $span(U \cup V)=U+V$.

$U \oplus W$ is the notation for $U+V,$ if $U \cap V=\{0\}$.